# failed to target with hash string 'android-O'

Tags: android, sdk, android-8.0-oreo

I am receiving this error when updating targetSDKVersion to android oreo

> Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-O' in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>
> Install missing platform(s) and sync project

when I am clicking on "Install missing platform(s) and sync project", it is showing a popup with this message.

[image]

I updated android SDK but it keep showing this popup.

Needed solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully test your app's compatibility with Android P and begin using new APIs, open your ***module-level*** **`build.gradle`** file and update the **`compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion`** as shown here:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    ...
}
```

Read [**`Set Up the Android P SDK`**](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk).

Comment: that helps. Thanks.